# F# Refer a module function from another file

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, .net-core

I am writing a very beginner's F# program (**F# Core** & **Visual Studio Code**) as follows:

1.Sort.fs

```
namespace Demo

module Sort =
    let rec quickSort list =
        match list with
        | [] -> []
        | head::tail ->
            let smalls =
                tail |> List.filter(fun c-> c<head)|> quickSort
            let bigs =
                tail |> List.filter(fun c-> c>=head)|> quickSort
            List.concat [smalls;[head];bigs]
```

2.Program.fs

```
namespace Demo

open Sort

module Program =
    let list = [3;1;8;4;9;5;7;6]

    [<EntryPoint>] 
    let main argv =
        list |> Sort.quickSort |> printfn "%A"       
        printfn "Hello World from F#!"
        0
```

However when I try to `open Sort` module into `Main` I am getting following errors:

> The namespace or module 'Sort' is not defined.
>
> The value, namespace, type or module 'Sort' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following:
>      sqrt

Where as, if I take sort module under same file - `Program.fs, everything works fine. Is there anything else needed to refer file as well?

Comment: File order is important in F# (for good reason). This will only work if `Sort.fs` comes before `Program.fs` in your project.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox, just for my knowledge - may I know where can I find these all or required **good reasons**?

Comment: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/cyclic-dependencies/

Comment: You can just edit the fsproj file by hand (i.e. move the line with Alt-Up/Down) or use its UI with the Projext Explorer to order the files in VS Code. You can have so called [recursive modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/modules) and types though where you can refer to a type before its definition.

Answer (score 8):

The order of files in the project explorer is very important. 
If you want to use module `Sort` from module `Program`, `Sort.fs` has to appear before `Program.fs`.

more information can be found [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-f/9780596802080/ch01s04.html), [here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/cycles-and-modularity-in-the-wild/) and [here](https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2016/02/f-beginner-tip-file-order-matters.html)